# Elastic Search Bulk Query Takes 30 minutes, is this normal?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, bigdata, cluster-computing, elasticsearch-6

I am storing about 20 million documents every day into an elastic search (6x) index with varying paramaters for my primary shard and replica counts ranging from 2 to 5 on both (this is running in a 5 node cluster with fast hardware) Every time I run a batch to pull all the documents from the index it takes upward of 30 minutes to iterate through all this data using scrolling and I've spent a lot of time trying to read up on things like setting the scroll size, using constant scores etc. without much luck of improving my search speed.

My question is, am I doing something totally wrong for a search query to take over 30 minutes sorted by a date/time field across 20 million records when I need to return all the fields (about 30 fields per document) or is that par for the course with bulk searches? My code is below showing how I build the query and execute it, and hoping someone can help me figure out if there is a better way to code this that would lead to faster performance.

```
    BoolQueryBuilder query = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
    if(_input.getStartTime() != null && _input.getStopTime() != null) {
        query.must(new TermQueryBuilder("XTYPE", 1));
        String fromDateTime = ElasticQueryHelper.createDateTimeStamp2(
                _input.getStreamDate(), _input.getStartTime());
        String toDateTime = ElasticQueryHelper.createDateTimeStamp2(
                _input.getStreamDate(),_input.getStopTime());

        LocalDateTime from = LocalDateTime.parse(fromDateTime,_dateTimeFormatter);
        LocalDateTime to = LocalDateTime.parse(toDateTime,_dateTimeFormatter);
        query.filter(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("XDATETIME")
                .from(fromDateTime).includeLower(true).to(toDateTime)
                .includeUpper(true));
    }
    ConstantScoreQueryBuilder queryWrapper = QueryBuilders.constantScoreQuery(query);
    try {
  SearchResponse response = null;
  response = _elasticTransport.getClient().prepareSearch()
  .setSearchType(SearchType.QUERY_THEN_FETCH)
  .setIndices(_input.getElasticIndex())
  .setTypes("row")
  .addStoredField("*")
  .setScroll(new TimeValue(50000))
  .setSize(20000)
  .setFetchSource(true)
 .setQuery(queryWrapper)
 .addSort("XDATETIME", SortOrder.ASC)
 .execute().actionGet();
        //
        return response;    
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new XCacheStreamWriterException("Exception executing elastic search query " + e.toString());
    }
```

Comment: Why are you pulling all documents daily?  Extracting from disk and transferring 20 million documents over the wire will take time, no matter how you do it.

Comment: The index captures a market data stream that I'm putting into a cache so I can rapidly back test trading systems. Querying directly from Elastic Search is incredibly slow.

Comment: I'm using this for a cache http://chronicle.software/products/chronicle-map/ where I pipe all the data into a single file on the file system.

Comment: @DuncanKrebs Have you considered using logstash with elasticsearch as the input and a local file as the output? Then your program could read this local file as needed, and you'd benefit from logstash's efficient elasticsearch querying.